# Use each line of piped output as parameter for script

Tags: bash, grep, pipeline

I have an application (myapp) that gives me a multiline output

result:

```
abc|myparam1|def
ghi|myparam2|jkl
mno|myparam3|pqr
stu|myparam4|vwx
```

With grep and sed I can get my parameters as below

```
myapp | grep '|' | sed -e 's/^[^|]*//' | sed -e 's/|.*//'
```

But then want these myparamx values as paramaters of a script to be executed for each parameter.

```
myscript.sh myparam1  
myscript.sh myparam2
etc.
```

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: Pfff, nearly impossible to post here

Comment: Useless use of double sed. `sed -e 's/^[^|]*//' | sed -e 's/|.*//' ` could be written as `sed -e 's/^[^|]*//' -e 's/|.*//' ` or even `sed -e 's/^[^|]*//; s/|.*//' `

Comment: Yes but sed is already hard to read so the double sed was to make that easier. Thanks anyway

Comment: hm... "read spaces as pipe symbol, didn't let me post". what's wrong with pipe symbols?

Answer (score 3):

Please see `xargs`. For example:

```
myapp | grep '|' | sed -e 's/^[^|]*//' | sed -e 's/|.*//' | xargs -n 1 myscript.sh
```

Comment: Just found out that xargs indeed seems to be the way to go.

Comment: Just found out that xargs indeed seems to be the way to go.  Thanks for answering, very helpfull

Comment: Just a note, I feel that you should replace both `sed` with a single `cut`: `cut -f 2 -d '|'`

Answer (score 2):

May be this can help -

```
myapp | awk -F"|" '{ print $2 }' | while read -r line; do /path/to/script/ "$line"; done
```

Answer (score 1):

I like the `xargs -n 1` solution from Dark Falcon, and `while read` is a classical tool for such kind of things, but just for completeness:

```
myapp | awk -F'|' '{print "myscript.sh", $2}' | bash
```

As a side note, speaking about extraction of 2nd field, you could use `cut`:

```
myapp | cut -d'|' -f 1 # -f 1 => second field, starting from 0
```